# ANTLR Propositional Logic Evaluator

Tags: java, eclipse, antlr, evaluate

I'm trying to create a grammar in ANTLR that evaluates propositional logic formulas. So for the input `(1 & 0) | 1`, it should return `true`.

I have constructed the following:

```
code returns[boolean value]
  : formula EOF {$value = $formula.value;}
  ; 

formula returns [boolean value]
  : equiv {$value = $equiv.value;}
  ; 

equiv returns [boolean value]
  : a=implies  {$value = $a.value;} 
  ( '#' b=implies {$value = $value == $b.value;}  
  )* 
  ;

implies returns [boolean value]
  : a=or   {$value = $a.value;} 
  ( '>' b=or {$value = !$value || $b.value;}
  )* 
  ;  

or returns [boolean value]
  : a=and {$value = $a.value;}
  ( '|' b=and {$value ||= $b.value;}
  )* 
  ;

and returns [boolean value]
  :  a=term {$value = $a.value;}
  ( '&' b=term {$value &&= $b.value;}
  )* 
  ; 

term returns [boolean value]
  : '(' formula ')' {$value = $formula.value;}
  | '0' {$value = false;}
  | '1' {$value = true;}
  | '¬' term {$value = !$term.value;}
  ;

WHITESPACE: (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\f'|'\n')+{$channel = HIDDEN;} ;
```

However I keep getting the error **java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: offendingToken**. Is there anyway to find out where the error is or how to fix it?

Comment: As a non-ANTLR expert, I debug these problems by looking at the generated Java code.  Your stack trace should include line numbers, and the generated code will have comments that indicate which part of which rule is represented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 issues:

- `{$value ||= $b.value;}` should be `{$value = $value || $b.value;}`
- `{$value &&= $b.value;}` should be `{$value = $value && $b.value;}`
- the label `$term` in the fourth alternative of the `term` rule is ambiguous: is could refer to the rule itself, or the `term` followed by `'¬'`

I.e., the following:

```java
term returns [boolean value]
  : ...
  | '¬' term {$value = !$term.value;}
  ;
```

should be:

```java
term returns [boolean value]
  : ...
  | '¬' t=term {$value = !$t.value;}
  ;
```

Having made those changes, the following test class:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String source = "(1 & 0) | 1";
    TestLexer lexer = new TestLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(source));
    TestParser parser = new TestParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    System.out.println(source + " = " + parser.code());
  }
}
```

produces the desired output:

```
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool Test.g
javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main

(1 & 0) | 1 = true
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help! I was trying to follow one of your earlier posts on evaluating +,-,/,* operations but could not see where I was going wrong here. I really thought ||= and &&= would be allowed. Thank you again!